# OR Tools taking infinite time for MVRP

Tags: python, or-tools, traveling-salesman, vehicle-routing

I am trying to solve MVRP problem using Google OR-Tools where I have 1000 points and 30 fleets(Vehicles). This seems to take indefinite amount of time but when I am reducing the fleets(vehicles) to 1 it is giving me solution.

The above situation gives me a fair Idea that TSP works well for google OR -Tools but MVRP stucks and takes huge amount of time.

Can anyone suggest me better ways, research papers or any blogs or articles where people scaled up MVRP problems?